# Is expression bounded as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: limits

I need to work out if an expression $f(x)/g(x)$ is bounded for a question about whether or not an acceptance-rejection algorithm is valid. I think the correct way to do so is to evaluate its limits at the end points, which I have already done for $x\to 0 $ but I am stuck on the following:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =  \lim_{x\to\infty} x^{k-1}\exp\{-x^k + \alpha x\}
$$
To have the above converge as $x\to 0 $ we will already require that $k>1$ and we are also told in the question that $k\neq 1$. We must also have $\alpha>0$.

Now what I want to know is if for it possible for some $k>1$ for the above expression to be bounded as $x\to\infty$? It appears to me that for any $k>1$ this couldn't be the case since the very first term $x^{k-1}$ would increase without bound?

Comment: Yes, the $x^{k-1}$ term does increase without bound, but this is multiplied by an $e^{-x^k}$ term, which decreases to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the logarithm of your expression:
$$
\log(x^{k-1})-x^k+\alpha x=
-x^k\left(1-\frac{(k-1)\log x}{x^k}-\frac{\alpha}{x^{k-1}}\right)
$$
Since $k>1$, it's easy to see that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(k-1)\log x}{x^k}=0
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\alpha}{x^{k-1}}=0
$$
Thus the term in parentheses has limit $1$ and therefore we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(\log(x^{k-1})-x^k+\alpha x)=-\infty
$$
implying
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{k-1}\exp\{-x^k + \alpha x\}=0
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it safe to always evaluate limits as you have done here by taking the log of the expression?

Comment: @DenisKelleher Yes, sure!

Answer (score 0):

Exponentials converge faster than polynomials. Anyway, you could find the limit using l'Hôpital.

Comment: Is what you mean by this that if you manipulated the expression as the product of three functions of x, the middle one with the e^{-x^k} would converge "fastest" toward zero and therefore the whole expression goes to zero?

Comment: That's the intuitive idea. Also, you don't need to separate it into three terms, because  $-x^k$ converges faster than $\alpha x$ no matter which $\alpha$ you take.